# Need to print value from 12th column of a particular row that matches two variables in a CSV file

Tags: awk, sed, csv, cut

Consider below two variables

```
DC="777777"
CountryCode="IN"
```

Have a CSV file, `fileSB.csv`. I found a command (below) to search for the `DC` variable name in 2nd column and `CountryCode` variable name in 4th column. Only if both variable matches in the same line, then that particular line will be printed.

Now my requirement is that in the same row/line as detected using below command, I want to print only the values present in 12th column. The problem here is that 12th column can have any number of commas in it and hence not able to print values in 12th column

Command to print line that matches both variable values from file name `fileSB.csv` is

```
awk -v pat1="$DC" -v pat2="$CountryCode" -F, '($2==pat1&&$4==pat2)' fileSB.csv
```

Summary: Need to get the 12th column from the comma-separated output of `awk`, which may contain any number of commas, and is followed by another 10 columns.

Comment: -1 for not putting requested information into the question (and for calling it a CSV file when it isn’t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comments below, the 12th column contains a variable number of comma-separated items, followed by 10 more columns.

```
awk -v pat1="$DC" -v pat2="$CountryCode" -F, '$2 == pat1 && $4 == pat2' fileSB.csv |
cut -d, -f 12- | rev | cut -d, -f 11- | rev
```

The `cut` and `rev` calls will first remove the 11 first columns, and then reverse the data and remove the last 10 column (now the first 10 columns after the reversal), and then reverse it again.

Comment: tried above command but it shows unbound variable

Comment: @user8554534 If I had any data to test on, I could try to reproduce what you're seeing. Do update you question with a bit of data that I and others could use to help you.

Comment: consider a excel file that many number of lines in it. Using command awk -v pat1="$DC" -v pat2="$CountryCode" -F, '$2 == pat1 && $4 == pat2' fileSB.csv, output is 1,7777777,hi, IN, one,two,three,four,five,six,red,114.14,15.21, 16 rr,ten,eleven                         where in the line value from 114.14,15.21, 16 rr represents 12th column value and the value inside the column can vary

Comment: since the value itself inside column has some comma's in it, need a command to exactly detect the value of 12th column

Comment: @user8554534 That's not a valid CSV formatted dataset. Column 12 should be quoted...  Is column 12 the last column?

Comment: 12th column is not the last one

Comment: @user8554534 Does the 12th column contain a constant number of commas then?

Comment: Another example 
36,777777,lica,IN,yyyy.IN 14.5,10/3/2017 16:30,10/3/2017 19:30,completed,third,14.5,ready,14.5 h,14.5f,14.6,d,completed,from,to        
consider 14.5 h,14.5f,14.6,d represents 12th column

Comment: 12th column does not have constant number of commas.

Comment: @user8554534 How many column are there after the 12th column? I'm just trying to find a way to delimit the 12th column from the other columns...

Comment: totally 22 columns, after 12th there are 10 columns

Comment: @user8554534 See updated answer. I might have an off-by-one error, but I'm not sure as you haven't provided a complete dataset to test with.

Comment: @user8554534 Additional information should go in the question, not in comments. This is particularly true of important information like example usage.